# Confidence Interval Estimation question

Tags: confidence-interval, inference

Is the confidence level of an interval only valid if the samples drawn are equal to the original sample size used when calculating the confidence level and interval? Why must it be equal?
Why not less than or equal?
Surely "less than or equal will have less variability and therefore likely to be within the interval?"

Any help would be much appreciated,

Comment: Welcome to the site! If you look at a formula for the confidence interval, you will notice that the (square root of the) sample size is baked right in! This is to make sure we widen or shorten our interval in response to exactly that change in variability you describe.